# How do I determine if an emit is defined?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have a button that can handle something with and without longPress.

Originally before I switched to emitters I used function callbacks since I had a React Native background.

So I did the typings as

```
export type UsePressableEmits =
  | {
      (e: "press", event: Event): void;
      (e: "longPress", event: Event): void;
    }
  | {
      (e: "press", event: Event): void;
    };
```

Right now this code block fails

```
  function fire(event: Event) {
    firing.value = true;
    emit("press", event);
    firing.value = false;
  }

  function fireLongPress(event: Event) {
    firing.value = true;
    emit("longPress", event); // does not pass type checks
    firing.value = false;
  }
```

`emit` is a function I pass that's built from

```
const emit = defineEmits<{
      (e: "press", event: Event): void;
      (e: "longPress", event: Event): void;
    }>()
```

Comment: What is `emit`?

Comment: Probably `e: "press" | "longPress"` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.

```
export type UsePressableEmits = {
  (e: 'press', event: Event): void
  (e: 'longpress', event: Event): void
}
```